# How to get CSRF token using Postman?

Tags: spring-boot, cookies, spring-security

I'm using Spring Security to generate the CSRF token for me.

```java
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .csrf()
            .csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse())
            .and() 
        ...etc
}
```

But I'm unable to find the cookies in Postman, no cookie found for `X-XSRF-TOKEN` to use.
[image]
[image]

Comment: its because its in a cookie, not a header, just as the documentation states and the screenshot is showing the headers, look to the left of the headers

Comment: What version of Spring Security are you using? In Spring Security 6, CSRF tokens are [deferred](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/5.8/migration/servlet/exploits.html#_defer_loading_csrftoken).

Comment: @Toerktumlare It seems like I did not read the docs related to Spring Security 6 , thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @SteveRiesenberg.
in Spring Security 6 , CSRF tokens are [defered](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/5.8/migration/servlet/exploits.html#_defer_loading_csrftoken)